Override the template for related products in WooCommerce
I'm having a problem with WooCommerce: It doesn't correctly pick up related products by showing those in the same categories. Do you have any ideas to forcibly set the display of products that are in the same category as the single product? Maybe I'm missing something...
I had no success trying to override the
template "\wp-content\themes-child\woocommerce\templates\single-product\related.php" via my child theme.
<?php
/**
 * Related Products
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $related_products ) : ?>

    <section class="related products">

        <?php
        $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_related_products_heading', __( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ) );

        if ( $heading ) :
            ?>
            <h2><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

                    <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </section>
    <?php
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();


The correct path for overriding that template is /wp-content/themes/yourchildtheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php without "templates" subfolder.

Try this woocommerce related product free plugin

This is the correct path you can override the template is
wp-content\theme\child-theme\woocommerce\single-product\related.php
    <section class="related products">

        <?php
        $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_related_products_heading', __( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ) );

        if ( $heading ) :
            ?>
            <h2><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

                    <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </section>

